# How to log to a text file using Custom Kurento OpenCV Module

Tags: c++, opencv, kurento

I have implemented an algorithm using Kurento OpenCV module and I need to be logging landmarks from each frame to a text file for analysis later, how best can I achieve this?

I am trying to create the file in the constructor:

```
myfile.open("/home/farai/Desktop/example.txt");
```

Then I am writing to the file findings from each frame:

```
for(int j = 0; j < shapes[i].NPoints(); j++){
    myfile << shapes[i][j].x << ":" << shapes[i][j].y <<"  ";
}
myfile<<"\n";
```

This is what I have tried but I don't have any file being created.

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, I seem to have found the way around it:

Kurento Media Server is run by a "Kurento" user presumably created during installation.

Running `sudo lsof -i:8888` will show the KMS process and the user owning the process.

This user will have restricted access to the host user's filesystem and thus appropriate access has to be granted to the path, something like `sudo chmod *** 777` !!! only if 777 is the right one for your case !!!